# Syntax error on token expected

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I'm attempting to resolve an issue with a

> syntax error on token "}" , { expected.

The program should be able to calculate tax on the amount enter.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Accounting {

/**
 * @param args
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //declare variables 
    int accountNumber;
    int age=0;
    int months=0;
    double amount=0.0;
    double increasedAmount=0.0;
    double incomeTax=0.0;
    double newAmount=0.0;
    char letter;
    double rate=0.03;
    double interest=0.0;
    double tax=0.40;
    double income=0.0;


    //get input 
    accountNumber=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the account number (Type 999 to exit "));
    age=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the age "));
    amount=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the amount "));
    months=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the number of months "));

    letter=(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "--- --- Main Menu --- --- --- " + 
    "\n A. Seniors Account " + "\n B. Income Tax " + "\n C. Special Accounts " + 
            "\n Please select a letter from the menu ( Type X to exit the Menu)")).charAt(0);



    //call function

    interest=amount*rate*months;

    income=amount*tax;

    increasedAmount=calcSenior(amount, interest);

    incomeTax=calcTax(amount, income );


    //display results 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The increased amount is " + increasedAmount);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The income tax is " + incomeTax);}



    public static void displayHeading()
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "############################# ");  
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Als Accounting Services       ");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your success is our business. ");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "############################# ");

    }



// code methods 

    //case 1:
    public static double calcSenior (double amt, double intest)
    {
        double cost; 
        cost=amt+intest;
        return cost;

    }

    //case 2:
    public static double calcTax(double amot, double inc)
    {
        double cost1;
        cost1=amot+inc;
        return cost1;

    }

    //case 3:
    public static void makeDeductions (int age, double amount)
    {
        double newAmount;
        if (age > 40)
        {
          newAmount=amount-100;
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Amount " + amount);
        }
        else 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No deductions at this time ");
        }
                 }
           } - error

    while (accountNumber != 999)
       {
          Accounting.displayHeading();

          switch (accountNumber)
          {
          case 1:
              calcSenior();
             break;

          case 2:
          calcTax();
          break;    

          case 3:
              makeDeductions();
              break;
              default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bye! Have a nice day ");

          }//end switch

       }
      }
      }
```

Comment: Could you please tell us where the exception is popping? (A stack trace would be helpful).

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at wk12a.Accounting.main(Accounting.java:18)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, your while loop is out side the body of the class definition...

```
public class Accounting {
    //...
} // End of class..

while...
```

This is illegal in Java.  You must place the while loop within a executional context, such as a method or static initialiser block...

Answer (score 2):

Your code's laid out unusually.  You've got a piece of `main` towards the top and towards the bottom.

Here's the quick (compiling) fix:

- Remove the curly brace at the end of `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The income tax is " + incomeTax);}`.
- Move the `while` loop to after that line.
- Fix the method calls from within your `while` loop so that the parameters that they're using are correct.

Admittedly, this says nothing about the correctness of your program, but only to the point that it would be much, much closer to compiling.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the `makeDeductions (int age, double amount)` method you have this:

```
 }
           } - error
```

That first `}` closes the method body, and the following `}` closes the class body, so that leaves you with a `- error` outside class body, illegal syntax in Java. Also, there's a `while` after that, also illegal outside method body (and of course illegal outside class body)

If you delete both of those lines (numbers 100 and 101, copypasting your code) that problem is resolved (though that `- error` probably does something, even if I can't figure out what, so be careful when deleting it). But there's one more:

- In what now would be part of the `makeDeductions (int age, double amount)` method body you now have references to variable `accountNumber` which is declared in the `main(String[] args)` method and thus doesn't exist in this context
- You call for `calcSenior()` when that overload doesn't exist, the only one you have declared is `calcSenior (double amt, double intest)` (notice the two parameters)
- Same for `calcTax()`, you have only declared `calcTax(double amot, double inc)`
- And yet the same for `makeDeductions ()`, with only `makeDeductions (int age, double amount)` having been declared. Careful here though, remember that I'm asuming you deleted those likes I specified at the beginning, so this code is INSIDE THE `makeDeductions (int age, double amount)` BODY, meaning that if you call `makeDeductions` with int and double parameters, you are in fact calling this very method, which can cause an infinite loop if you don't have a stopping condition to avoid the method to call itself infinitely (causing a stack overflow)

And that's all I could find. I hope this is useful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using Eclipse as IDE and trying to run code that doesn't compile. Check your Problems view in Eclipse, and fix the compilation errors before executing the application.